# RxJs: sequential sending of requests is not really sequential

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs

I need to send a set of identical requests sequentially: the next request should be sent only when the previous is complete (i.e. I got the response). I'm having the following code...

```
Observable.of(ids)
    .pipe(
        concatMap(ids => ids.map(id => this.doRequest(id)))
    )
    .subscribe((res) => { 
        //one more request here 
    })
```

The next request do not wait for previous to complete. Moreover when I do one more request in subscribe `N` requests (where `N` is equal to `ids.length`) are sent instead of one request.

Can someone explain me what is happening here and how can I fix the problem?

Thank you in advance!

**UPD.** Looks like it's needed to provide more details on what I'm trying to do. After following @martin answer the code looks like the following

```
let obj = {ids: [1, 2, 3]};

return Observable.of(obj)
    .filter((tube: ResultTube) => {
        return (
            obj != null &&
            obj.ids &&
            obj.ids.length > 0
        );
    })
    .switchMap(obj => {
        return Observable.from(obj.ids);
    })
    .pipe(
        concatMap(id => this.approveLaboratory(id))
    )
    .map((res) => { 
        debugger; //fired N times after subscribe() !
        return obj 
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want `concatMap` to wait you need to work with single emissions and let it process them one by one. What you have right now pushes `ids` as an array into `concatMap` and then creates an array of Observables. Instead you can unpack `ids` into separate emissions before `concatMap`:

```
Observable.from(ids)
  .pipe(
    concatMap(id => this.doRequest(id))
  )
  .subscribe((res) => { 
    //one more request here 
  })
```

...or like this:

```
Observable.of(ids)
  .pipe(
    concatAll(), // unpack array of ids
    concatMap(id => this.doRequest(id))
  )
  .subscribe((res) => { 
    //one more request here 
  })
```

Comment: thank you for your answer! I've reoranized the code (see update of question) still `debugger` is fired `N` times, that is not OK for me. How can I fix that?

Comment: That's correct, its called for each item but your problem was that it wasn't called sequentialy.

Comment: Yes, that's another problem. Still I need to find a fix for it

Comment: You can use `toArray()` to collect all responses or you can use `ignoreElements()` so you won't receive any value it depends on what you want to do.